# Simulation of time series with R

Tags: r, time-series, simulation

I'm new on time series. I'm trying to solve an exercise on the simulation of an ARMA process.

The problem is the following: 
Generate 100 simulations, each with n=60 elements of an ARMA(1,2) process with mean $\mu=1.25$ and parameters $\phi_1=-0.5$, $\theta_1=0.5$, $\theta_2=-0.7$ and $\sigma^2=0.5$
For each simulation estimate the mean and the first two correlation coefficients and find in how many simulations they are contained in the theoretical confidence intervals.

Ok so, I think that for one simulation of the ARMA(1,2) I should do something like:

```
x <- arima.sim(list(order = c(1,0,2), ar = -0.5 , ma=c(0.5, -0.7)), sd=sqrt(0.5), n = 60)
```

And this is one simulation, right? But then, for generate the other 99 simulation what should I do? Can I construct a kind of a loop?

Thank you in advance ! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
M=matrix(ncol=60,nrow=100)
for(i in 1:100){
  x = arima.sim(list(order = c(1,0,2), ar = -0.5 , ma=c(0.5, -0.7)), sd=sqrt(0.5), n = 60)
  M[i,]=x
}
```

note that every row of matrix $M$ contains a simulation.

See also *Stephan Kolassa* comment for an alternative.

Comment: Or use `replicate()`, as in `M <- replicate(100, arima.sim(list(order=c(1,0,2),ar=-0.5,ma=c(0.5,-0.7)),sd=sqrt(0.5),n=60))` (note that then every *column* of `M` will contain a time series, not every row).